# Using npm nswag to generate TypeScript files from Swagger .json files containing OData values

Tags: odata, swagger, nswag

I am using npm [nswag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nswag) to generate a TypeScript file from a Swagger .json file with the swaggerToTypeScriptClient code generator.

There is a problem when it comes across [OData](http://www.odata.org/) properties contained in the JSON. When it generates the interface, the TypeScript throws an error because it does not recognise the '@' in the OData property value.

This is an example of the original Swagger .json:

```
"Swashbuckle.OData.ODataResponse[System.Collections.Generic.List[Shadow.DataLayer.ReleaseBatchs]]": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "@odata.context": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "value": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Shadow.DataLayer.ReleaseBatchs"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the corresponding TypeScript generated by the nswag swaggerToTypeScriptClient:

```
export interface ReleaseBatchs {
    @odata.context?: string | undefined;
    value?: ReleaseBatchs2[] | undefined;
}
```

This throws an error because it does not like the '@' in the property.

It would work if the generated code wrapped the property in quotes, like this:

```
export interface ReleaseBatchs {
    "@odata.context"?: string | undefined;
    value?: ReleaseBatchs2[] | undefined;
}
```

Is there a way to get the swaggerToTypeScriptClient to wrap these properties in quotes? Or to make it compatible with OData values?

Comment: We have to fix this here: https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/blob/master/src/NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.TypeScript/Models/PropertyModel.cs#L38 ill look into this soon...

Comment: OK. Thanks for this. I have created a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in NSwag v11.3